# ¿como puedo subir varias imagenes con php y mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quiero insertar varias imágenes en mi base de datos con `PHP` para ser mas exacto 8 imágenes y mi problema es que quiero que se inserten las imágenes que solo el usuario coloque en el input esto son los input:

```
<!--primera imagen-->
<input type="file" name="producto" id="producto" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display: none;" required>

<label for="producto"><img src="Imagenes/previsua.png" id="imagenPrevisualizacion"  style="width: 125px; height:125px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;left: 10px;top: 10px; background-image: url(Imagenes/maxresdefault.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 40px 80px; background-position: center;"></label>

<!--segunda imagen-->
<input type="file" name="producto2" id="producto2" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display: none;" >

<label for="producto2" ><img src="Imagenes/previsua.png" id="imagenPrevisualizacion2"  style="width: 125px; height:125px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;left: 33px;top: 10px;  background-image: url(Imagenes/maxresdefault.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 40px 80px; background-position: center;"></label>

<!--tercera imagen-->
<input type="file" name="producto3" id="producto3" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display: none;" >

<label for="producto3" ><img src="Imagenes/previsua.png" id="imagenPrevisualizacion3"  style="width: 125px; height:125px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;left: 50px;top: 10px; background-image: url(Imagenes/maxresdefault.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 40px 80px; background-position: center;"></label>

<!--cuarta imagen-->
<input type="file" name="producto4" id="producto4" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display: none;" >

<label for="producto4" ><img src="Imagenes/previsua.png" id="imagenPrevisualizacion4"  style="width: 125px; height:125px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;left: 70px;top: 10px;  background-image: url(Imagenes/maxresdefault.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 40px 80px; background-position: center;"></label>

<!--quinta imagen-->
<input type="file" name="producto5" id="producto5" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display: none;" >

<label for="producto5" ><img src="Imagenes/previsua.png" id="imagenPrevisualizacion5"  style="width: 125px; height:125px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;left: 10px;top: 30px; background-image: url(Imagenes/maxresdefault.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 40px 80px; background-position: center;"></label>

<!--sexta imagen-->
<input type="file" name="producto6" id="producto6" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display: none;" >

<label for="producto6" ><img src="Imagenes/previsua.png" id="imagenPrevisualizacion6"  style="width: 125px; height:125px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;left: 30px;top: 30px;  background-image: url(Imagenes/maxresdefault.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 40px 80px; background-position: center;"></label>

<!--sextima imagen-->
<input type="file" name="producto7" id="producto7" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display: none;">

<label for="producto7" ><img src="Imagenes/previsua.png" id="imagenPrevisualizacion7"  style="width: 125px; height:125px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;left: 50px;top: 30px;  background-image: url(Imagenes/maxresdefault.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 40px 80px; background-position: center;"></label>

<!--octava imagen-->
<input type="file" name="producto2" id="producto8" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" style="display: none;" >

<label for="producto8" ><img src="Imagenes/previsua.png" id="imagenPrevisualizacion8"  style="width: 125px; height:125px; cursor: pointer; position: relative;left: 70px;top: 30px; background-image: url(Imagenes/maxresdefault.jpg);  background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 40px 80px; background-position: center;"></label>
```

y si se insertan pero yo quiero que solo se inserten los que el usuario suba. Esta es la parte de la inserción:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['Enviar'])) {
        session_start();
        if (!$_SESSION['verificar']) {
        echo '<script>alert("Es necesario Iniciar Sesion");</script>';
        echo '<script>setTimeout(function() { location.href="IniciarSesion.php"; }, 500);  </script>';
        //header( "refresh:0.5; url=IniciarSesion.php" );
        } else {
            include"configuracion/config.php";

            $id_user=$_SESSION['id'];
            $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
            $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
            $precio=$_POST['precio'];

            $nombreArchivo=$_FILES['producto']['name'];
            $Archivo=$_FILES['producto']['tmp_name'];
            $ruta='productos';
            $ruta=$ruta."/".$nombreArchivo;
            move_uploaded_file($Archivo, $ruta);

            $nombreArchivo2=$_FILES['producto2']['name'];
            $Archivo2=$_FILES['producto2']['tmp_name'];
            $ruta2='productos';
            $ruta2=$ruta2."/".$nombreArchivo2;
            move_uploaded_file($Archivo2, $ruta2);

            $nombreArchivo3=$_FILES['producto3']['name'];
            $Archivo3=$_FILES['producto3']['tmp_name'];
            $ruta3='productos';
            $ruta3=$ruta3."/".$nombreArchivo3;
            move_uploaded_file($Archivo3, $ruta3);

            $nombreArchivo4=$_FILES['producto4']['name'];
            $Archivo4=$_FILES['producto4']['tmp_name'];
            $ruta4='productos';
            $ruta4=$ruta4."/".$nombreArchivo4;
            move_uploaded_file($Archivo4, $ruta4);

            //imagen5
            $nombreArchivo5=$_FILES['producto5']['name'];
            $Archivo5=$_FILES['producto5']['tmp_name'];
            $ruta5='productos';
            $ruta5=$ruta5."/".$nombreArchivo5;
            move_uploaded_file($Archivo5, $ruta5);

            //imagen6
            $nombreArchivo6=$_FILES['producto6']['name'];
            $Archivo6=$_FILES['producto6']['tmp_name'];
            $ruta6='productos';
            $ruta6=$ruta6."/".$nombreArchivo6;
            move_uploaded_file($Archivo6, $ruta6);

            //imagen7
            $nombreArchivo7=$_FILES['producto7']['name'];
            $Archivo7=$_FILES['producto7']['tmp_name'];
            $ruta7='productos';
            $ruta7=$ruta7."/".$nombreArchivo7;
            move_uploaded_file($Archivo7, $ruta7);

            //imagen8
            $nombreArchivo8=$_FILES['producto8']['name'];
            $Archivo8=$_FILES['producto8']['tmp_name'];
            $ruta8='productos';
            $ruta8=$ruta8."/".$nombreArchivo8;
            move_uploaded_file($Archivo8, $ruta8);

            $fecha= date("d/m/y");

            $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db3 (id_user,Titulo, Descripcion, Precio, Producto, Producto2, Producto3,Producto4, Producto5, Producto6, Producto7, Producto8, Fecha) values ('$id_user','$titulo','$descripcion','$precio','$ruta', '$ruta2', '$ruta3', '$ruta4' , '$ruta5', '$ruta6', '$ruta7' , '$ruta8','$fecha')");

            echo '<script>setTimeout(function() { location.href="Inicio.php"; }, 500);  </script>';

        }     
    }
?>
```

He utilizado `if(isset y empty)` para insertar solo los que el usuario seleccione pero no me funciona y quisiera saber que método pudiese utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar la [variable `$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files) se utiliza la [función `empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) de **PHP**. Esta variable es un arreglo que contiene los archivos que vienen desde el request, cada archivo es un índice del arreglo, y para comprobar los índices se usa la [función `isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset) de **PHP** de la siguiente forma:

```
// ACÁ SE COMPRUEBA QUE EL ARREGLO $_FILES TENGA ELEMENTOS
// LÓGICAMENTE SI VIENEN ARCHIVOS EN EL REQUEST, ESTE ARREGLO NO ESTARÁ VACÍO
// POR ESO LA NEGACIÓN
if ( !empty( $_FILES ) ) {

    // LUEGO PARA VERIFICAR QUE UN ELEMENTO EXISTE DENTRO DE UN ARREGLO
    // USAMOS LA FUNCIÓN isset DE PHP
    if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'archivo1' ] ) ) {
        echo $_FILES[ 'archivo1' ][ 'name' ];
        // OTRAS OPERACIONES...
    }

    if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'archivo2' ] ) ) {
        echo $_FILES[ 'archivo2']['name' ];
        // OTRAS OPERACIONES...
    }
}
```

Los índices que se ocupan en la [variable `$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files) `archivo1` y `archivo2` son los que vienen de los elementos *input file* de **HTML** en los atributos `name`. El **HTML** quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="archivo1" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
    <input type="file" name="archivo2" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">

    <input type="submit" value="Subir Archivos">
</form>
```

**Referencias**:

- La documentación de **PHP** tiene un [artículo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php) acerca de la subida de archivos.